# getQty() is not working i can not take each quantity per Item?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have tried getTotalQtyOrdered() but still not success, Any idea guys?

```
    $dirPath = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'export';

if (!is_dir($dirPath)) {
mkdir($dirPath, 0777, true);
}

foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){

  $data[] = array(

        'ID'    => $item->getSku(),
        'QTY'   => $item->getQty(),
        'PRICE' => $item->getPrice()

        );

     }


    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>');
    foreach ($data as $item) {
    $xmlItem = $xml->addChild('item');
    foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
            $xmlItem->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }

    file_put_contents($dirPath. DS .$order->getIncrementId().'.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See sales_flat_order_item table in the database to see what values are stored. Alternatively you can also get a view of the data fields with `var_dump($item->debug());`.

You are likely looking for

```
$item->getQtyOrdered()
```

or potentially

```
$item->getQtyInvoiced()
```

Comment: This is the result i get:  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<ID>10000002</ID>
<QTY/>
<PRICE>171.34</PRICE>
</item>
<item>
<ID>10000005</ID>
<QTY/>
<PRICE>555</PRICE>
</item>
</root>   In both cases.

Comment: It was $item->getQtyOrdered() thank you very much.